# In Python, how can I push items one by one to an iterator consumed by another function?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Say I have an existing function that consumes an iterable, e.g.:

```
def printall(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        print(item)
```

The point is, the function already exists and I don't want to have to clone or modify it.

But I'd like to feed it with some nontrivial processing. Pseudocode:

```
push_handle = XXXX()
printall(push_handle)
# printall() is now waiting on next(iter(iterable))

for item0 in some_source():
    statement
    statement
    item1 = some_transformation(item0)
    push_handle.send(item1)
    # at this point printall() iterates once and resumes waiting
```

I'm aware that I could refactor the above loop to be a generator itself:

```
def processing(iterable):
    for item0 in iterable:
        statement
        statement
        item1 = some_transformation(item0)
        yield item1

printall(processing(some_source()))
```

Even so, it feels to me as though an "adapter" of the form sketched above would be useful, eliminating the need to refactor.

I've worked with Python generators, but I keep getting stumped by the fact that in a generator function, `yield` implicitly yields to the original caller. I imagine a class containing two generator methods, one whose `yield` expression receives `send()` calls and the other of which `yield`s to some other caller -- but transferring control from one to the other is the disconnect.

I could do this with threads and queues, but that feels too heavyweight for the purpose.

Similarly, I could use [eventlet.queue.Queue(0)](https://eventlet.net/doc/modules/queue.html), but the producer and consumer would have to be run on different eventlet greenthreads.

This feels as though it should be as straightforward as coding `yield`, but I'm stuck. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Does that `processing` function work? That's pretty much the answer: You're looking to produce an iterable that lazily provides elements upon request, and that's exactly what a generator is.

Comment: Is `printall()` allowed to exhaust the iterable and end or is there an expectation that it sits around and waits for more items to "appear" in the iterable?

Comment: While `printall` waits, the execution can only continue either (1) in the generator/iterator used by `printall` itself, (2) in a separate thread/process or (3) in an asynchronous task. You have already looked at all these options.

Comment: `processing()` is of course a workaround, which I'm using, but I'm still curious as to whether there's some way to achieve what I'm asking.

Comment: @JonSG I didn't write an explicit `push_handle.close()`, but that's how I imagine `printall()` would exit.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you did want a queue or some other polling based implementation.

Comment: @NatGoodspeed So with each `push_handle.send(item)` call you want to consume/forward `printall` generator previously activated and which can potentially be consumed by other callers?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The behavior I would like is that `push_handle.send(item)` transfers control to the implicit `next(iter(iterable))` underlying the `for` loop in `printall()`. `printall()` runs until it hits `next()` again, at which point control returns from `send()`.